# how to cast variable data in wp7withC#?

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-3.0, var

I have one variable and this variable contain multiple data.
I want to find perticuler one data so how i can find it?

my code is like

```
private void g1_Hold(object sender, Microsoft.Phone.Controls.GestureEventArgs e)
        {
             var item=(sender as StackPanel).DataContext;                           
        }
```

Here item contain multiple data like id, name ,imagepath,songpath etc.

Now i want just imagepath so how i can get it.

Help me .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one.

Hope its working if you store data in class.

```
private void g1_Hold(object sender, Microsoft.Phone.Controls.GestureEventArgs e)
        {
              StackPanel stk = (StackPanel)sender;
              ClassName sg = (ClssName)stk.DataContext;
              string path=sg.imagepath;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its Quite easy store data into array or list than find  position of data

For example

EDIT:

```
ListBox lst = (ListBox)sender;
   classname obj = (classname)lst.SelectedItem;
```

now you can use obj.anything you want

Comment: :thanks but list is not supported.I mean casting error is occured

Comment: now please tell me what is your purpose...please explain in brif

Comment: Actully i have one list box and i wants to selected item on hold event of list box...and i found selected item is in my variable but not get indivisully

Comment: first i store all data in list and this list is binded with data list. And also i have one class so all data is stored in class

Comment: thanks but hold event not contain selected item i tryed but in hold event its not possible